# Where is the config file that allows you to edit the text for invoking root via terminal?

Tags: ubuntu, configure

The current text is "`[sudo] password for $username:`". Where is the config file that allows you to modify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

> $ strings $(which sudo)  | grep 'password for'

What it is telling: many text strings shown in the terminal are part of the executables you launch.

**More to ponder on:**

Changing text strings (prompts) like the above may actually be a security issue; replace the text and the user may get very false indication of what actually is going on. Opening up for hacker attacks and whatnot.

**Localization:**
As has been pointed out in the comments; the above isn't the entire truth; if you see prompts and other text in a local language, then these texts has been read in from files for translation, related to but **separate from the executables**. Which of them (and when they appear) depends on the localization settings.

With enough knowledge about the translation system you may create your own 'translation'.

Comment: Not quite. In Ubuntu `sudo` is localized. My locale is `pl_PL.UTF-8` and instead of `password for` I see `hasło użytkownika`. With `strace` I learnt `sudo` looks in `/usr/share/locale/pl*/LC_MESSAGES/sudo.mo` and `/usr/share/locale-langpack/pl*/LC_MESSAGES/sudo.mo`. But the localized string comes from `/usr/share/locale-langpack/pl/LC_MESSAGES/sudoers.mo`. I don't know the exact mechanism so I won't write an answer. All I know is your answer does not tell the whole story.

Comment: As I refuse to use a localized system, I have come to totally disregard any translations. This decision is based on many mishaps, the worst one is the fact that Excel in a SWEDISH localized Office has e.g. `=CONCATENATE()` translated to `=SAMMANFOGA()` - any VBA functions you write in an English Excel - WILL NOT WORK in that Localized version of Office and vise versa.

Comment: Yes, Excel went too far. Another example: if there's a problem with `SAMMANFOGA`, searching it in the Internet won't give you potentially useful answers discussing `CONCATENATE`. Back to your answer, now I think it's useful enough to be upvoted.